# Uploading image to server in android without using String

Tags: android, mysql, image

I am uploading the image from my android application using String i.e; everytime I want to upload image onto server side I have to decode the image to String using Base64 and add it to

```
List<NameValuePair> list;
```

and send it to server, the server stores that String into the database and when I request to view the image they provide me that String image in response then I have to encode the String to image and there is a situation where image is much larger and the table can't hold the full value so it passes me the incomplete String in response and its banged. 
Is there any way where I can put the image directly onto server without converting it on to String everytime sometimes it seem to be very inefficient.
Is PUT method will be useful? Can I use PUT method to upload file directly.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **FileBody** of the HttpClient(apache) library that comes with android. Personally I prefer to use [HttpRequest](https://github.com/kevinsawicki/http-request) library.Just copy HttpRequest.java file in your project. Heres how you upload a image to server:

```
HttpRequest request = HttpRequest.post("http://google.com");
request.part("status[body]", "Making a multipart request");
request.part("status[image]", new File("/home/kevin/Pictures/ide.png"));
if (request.ok())
  System.out.println("Status was updated");
```

Comment: request.part("key","value");
Is it like that
what server will receiver??

Comment: yes its as simple as that the "key" is the parameter you use as $_POST['key'] in your serer if you are using php.

Comment: Server is running node.js and image will go as image where server program will store the image as when i was sending string it was being stored in database table.

Comment: this is the http post method with a file just like browsers do it. I dont know about node.js but it is http post so all programs support it